# Decrypt files encrypted with TrueCrypt

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, cryptography, algorithm

I have a usb pen memory crypted with TrueCrypt.

Is there a way to decrypt ( without TrueCrypt ) files encrypted with TrueCrypt in linux ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TrueCrypt volumes can only be decrypted with TrueCrypt itself.

Comment: No longer true - dmcrypt now has support for the TrueCrypt file format.  This is especially useful now that the TC product has been discontinued (http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/), though they still offer a decryption application to facilitate moving to a maintained product.

Answer (score 1):

Since about 2014(?) this is trivially done with *cryptsetup*:

```
cryptsetup tcryptOpen <device> <name>
```

For example:

```
cryptsetup tcryptOpen /dev/sdx1 my_tc
mount /dev/mapper/my_tc /mnt
...
umount /mnt
cryptsetup close my_tc
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use Truecrypt (that's the whole point of encryption), however you can use the Windows version of Truecrypt to decrypt linux-created Truecrypt volumes, AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

```
    How to Remove Encryption : 
1-Mount your TrueCrypt volume.
2-Move all files from the TrueCrypt volume to any location outside the TrueCrypt
   volume (note that the files will be decrypted on the fly).
3-Dismount the TrueCrypt volume.
4-If the TrueCrypt volume is file-hosted, delete it (the container) just like 
    you delete any other file.
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for a non-TrueCrypt method (which is not possible).