# Examples of encrypted hot-swap RAID NAS for SOHO use?

Tags: encryption, raid, nas, soho

As per title.
Does an encrypted hot-swap RAID NAS even exist?

Comment: You probably know this but do make sure you have several backups of your encryption keys and/or recovery keys. Also do make separate backups of your data, if the backups are also encrypted, make sure you can decrypt them without the use of your current computer. Obvious stuff I know, but a lot [of](http://superuser.com/q/141502/52492) [questions](http://superuser.com/questions/75773/recover-files-encyrpted-in-bitlocker) [here](http://superuser.com/q/256619/52492) suggest many people don't make backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, most high end NAS has it. For example http://www.qnap.com/pro_application.asp?ap_id=319

or http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/business/terastation-iii-ts-xlr5/